# Alternative to Scalar Function in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database

Instead of below query what I can use to convert sql data to json object.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ES_GetSchools](@IdListing NVARCHAR(400))
 RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)  
 AS
 BEGIN
 RETURN(
    SELECT   
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolDistrictId,'')<>'' THEN 
            SUBSTRING(SchoolDistrictId,1,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolDistrictId)-1)ELSE NULL END AS 'district.name',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolDistrictId,'')<>'' THEN 
            SUBSTRING(SchoolDistrictId,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolDistrictId)+1,LEN(SchoolDistrictId))ELSE NULL END AS 'district.id',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolDistrictSEOPath,'')<>'' AND SchoolDistrictSEOPath<>'0'  THEN 
            SchoolDistrictSEOPath ELSE NULL end 'district.seo',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolElementary,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolElementary)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolElementary,1,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolElementary)-1) ELSE SchoolElementary END ELSE NULL END AS 'elementary.name',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolElementary,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolElementary)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolElementary,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolElementary)+1,LEN(SchoolElementary)) ELSE NULL END ELSE NULL END AS 'elementary.id',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolHigh,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolHigh)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolHigh,1,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolHigh)-1)ELSE SchoolHigh END ELSE NULL END AS 'high.name',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolHigh,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolHigh)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolHigh,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolHigh)+1,len(SchoolHigh))ELSE NULL END ELSE NULL END AS 'high.id',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolMiddle,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolMiddle)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolMiddle,1,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolMiddle)-1)ELSE SchoolMiddle END  ELSE NULL END AS 'middle.name',
            CASE WHEN ISNULL(SchoolMiddle,'')<>'' THEN 
            CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(':',SchoolMiddle)>0 THEN
            SUBSTRING(SchoolMiddle,CHARINDEX(':',SchoolMiddle)+1,len(SchoolMiddle))ELSE NULL END ELSE NULL END AS 'middle.id'
    FROM  Table_Name1 a WITH (NOLOCK)
          WHERE  a.IdListing = @IdListing 
FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
)
END

GO

SELECT dbo.[ES_GetSchools](Idlisting) from Table_Name1 a join Table_Name2 b on a.idlisting=b.idlisting
```

Comment: Use an inline table-value function? What do you mean "instead of"?

Comment: Expecting an alternative solution.

Comment: Be careful with that NOLOCK hint. It has hidden surprises that many don't know about or understand. https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: What kind of alternative? What is your actual goal here? "How do I do this differently" isn't a question that can really be answered unless we know what you're aiming for.

Comment: The main goal of the query mentioned in summary is to give the json result like below and also it works good for few datas,but when working with millions(20) of data the function is very slow.
{
  "district": {
    "name": "Boston School District",
    "id": "2000230000045",
    "seo": "boston-boston-ma"
  },
  "elementary": {
    "name": "BPS"
  },
  "high": {
    "name": "BPS"
  },
  "middle": {
    "name": "BPS"
  }
}


When i convert the scalar to Inline function it throws an error

CREATE FUNCTION failed because a column name is not specified for column 1.

Comment: Then give the column a name.

Comment: Please update the tags of your questions with the version of SQL Server. SQL Server 2016 and later have native JSON support, so it is important to know your target SQL Server version

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax

```
SELECT field1, field2
FROM table
FOR JSON AUTO
```